# Extract float/double value

Tags: python, regex

How do I extract a double value from a string using regex.

```
import re

pattr = re.compile(???)    
x = pattr.match("4.5")
```

Comment: Could you provide some details on why you can't use float("4.5")?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's the easy way.  Don't use regex's for built-in types.

```
try:
    x = float( someString )
except ValueError, e:
    # someString was NOT floating-point, what now?
```

Comment: Actually, this is also the safest way. Consider some wrong input, like `0..1`, `0.0.02`, it's very difficult for regex to recognise it. The worse thing is, it will pretend it's correct and produce some wrong answer.

Comment: Technically correct, but the question explicitly specifies regexp.

Answer (score 62):

A regexp from the [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Building-a-regexp):

```
import re
re_float = re.compile("""(?x)
   ^
      [+-]?\ *      # first, match an optional sign *and space*
      (             # then match integers or f.p. mantissas:
          \d+       # start out with a ...
          (
              \.\d* # mantissa of the form a.b or a.
          )?        # ? takes care of integers of the form a
         |\.\d+     # mantissa of the form .b
      )
      ([eE][+-]?\d+)?  # finally, optionally match an exponent
   $""")
m = re_float.match("4.5")
print m.group(0)
# -> 4.5
```

To extract numbers from a bigger string:

```
s = """4.5 abc -4.5 abc - 4.5 abc + .1e10 abc . abc 1.01e-2 abc 
       1.01e-.2 abc 123 abc .123"""
print re.findall(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", s)
# -> ['4.5', '-4.5', '- 4.5', '+ .1e10', ' 1.01e-2',
#     '       1.01', '-.2', ' 123', ' .123']
```

Comment: Note that this also matches integer numbers (which is expected because every integer is also a floating point number)

Answer (score 20):

For parse int and float (point separator) values:

```
re.findall( r'\d+\.*\d*', 'some 12 12.3 0 any text 0.8' )
```

result:

```
['12', '12.3', '0', '0.8']
```

Comment: If you may offer a procedure to get the int or float but without it being in a dictionary or array then it would helpful.
what i have
`str1 = "BIOS:      version 2.0.0"`
what i want
 `2.0.0`
without any comma or brackets.

Comment: Hello, you may used like:       re.findall( r'[\d\.]+', "BIOS: version 2.0.0" )

Comment: better: re.findall( r'[\d\.]{2,}|\d+', "BIOS: version 2.0.0" )

Comment: simple and exact

Answer (score 1):

a float as regular expression in brute force. there are smaller differences to the version of J.F. Sebastian:

```
import re
if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = str(1.000e-123)
  reFloat = r'(^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]\d+)?$)'
  print re.match(reFloat,x)

>>> <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0054D3E0>
```

Comment: This doesn't match floats without an integer part, e.g. `.123` instead of `0.123`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that none of these answers cover the interesting edge cases such as "inf", "NaN", "-iNf", "-NaN", "1e-1_2_3_4_5_6", etc.

(inspired by Eric's answer here [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python))