# removing all numbers from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, digits

I have a text that is tokenized. Inside there numbers like 1.2, 2.3, etc 
I used the following codes to remove them but they do not work

```
train_vs['doc_text'] = train_vs['doc_text'].apply(lambda x: [c for c in x if not c.isnumeric()])
train_vs['doc_text'] = train_vs['doc_text'].apply(lambda x: [c for c in x if not c.isdigit()])
```

Any help on how to remove these digits?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

`.apply` is a method of both `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` and you are calling it on a `Series`. The upshot here is that every `x` for your lambda is a value in your dataframe. If you really have a tokenized list in each value of your `Series` then I'm not sure that's ideal.

Anyway, `isdigit` and `isnumeric` can't check for floats out of the box. A silly workaround could look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'smple':[
    ["12.34", "atrium"],
    ["12.34", "atrium"],["election", "foible"],
    ['USA', "2131244213213"]
        ]
    }
)


df.smple.apply(
    lambda x: [c for c in x if not (c.isnumeric() or c.replace('.','',1).isdigit())]
)
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python) would be helpful reading for you I think.

Comment: hi,Thanks a lot for your help. unfortunately though, your code worked for some numbers, but not all of them. I still have numbers like 1.23, -3.45.. etc. especially negative numbers.