# Input function isn't working how I thought it works

Tags: python

So I was doing some really basic programming because I'm very new, and I wanted to do user inputs from the console to define variables. I though the `input()` function would do it, but I think it's taking what I put in as a string instead.

I stripped down all the code to a really basic program that just multiplies the given number. I've tried putting in raw_input(), but my online compiler doesn't like that. `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`

```
n = input("Number:")
print(n*2)
```

Instead all it does it print the number twice, (5 would be 55, 2 would be 22 etc.)

Comment: `input` in `python3` return `str`. So if you tried to do `'x' * 2` you will get `xx` :). Note: there is not `raw_input` in `python3`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
n = input("Number:")
if(n.isdigit()):
    n=int(n)
    print(n*2)
else:
    print("N is not a digit")
```

This will ensure if the input is not a digit, you do not try to convert it to a int.

If you would like to check if `n` is a float() meaning `n.n` then you should check out this question on [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python). Then you can replace `int(n)` with `float(n)` in the if statement above.

Answer (score 1):

Convert n to an integer first.

```
n = input("Number:")
m = int(n)
print(m*2)
```

or just

```
n = input("Number:")
print(int(n)*2)
```

Note that this will fail with a `ValueError` if you type alphabetical characters for your input. A simple way to catch this would be to put the int conversion (you can do a `float` conversion the same way if you prefer) between a try-except block as follows:

```
n = input("Number:")
try:
    print(int(n)*2)
except(ValueError):
    print("Please enter digits only.")
```

Comment: This is a neat solution but you should add a check to verify if the input is actually a number.

Comment: @Gio That's an important point. I edited my answer to add one.