# How can I count elements in a list by type?

Tags: python

I want to know how to count elements in a list with various types of elements(numbers/characters/symbols)?

```
myList = ['8', 'K' , '&' ,'2', '$' , '3' , 'T','R']
```

The result will be 3, if I want to count numbers.

```
l=["wael", "dd", ";D"]
l.clear()
print("Input the list size")
n=(int(input()))
for i in range(1,n+1):
 print("fill spot",i,"of the list with")
 l.append(input())
d=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
 if 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 in l:
    d=d+1
print("number=",d)
```

Comment: What did you try? It's easier to help with the code. Please edit your question and add relevant code.

Comment: ***numbers/characters/symbols*** - do you mean numbers/letters/symbols ? characters are all of them.

Comment: The line `if 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 in l` is equivalent to `if False or True or True or ... or 9 in l`. Also, please read the help center's guide on creating [minimal, complete, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What about *floats* where should they be added. They have number and a `.` character in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
L = ['8', 'K' , '&' ,'2', '$' , '3' , 'T','R', 5.4, "3.2"]
number_count = 0

for data in L:
    if isinstance(data,int) or isinstance(data, float) or data.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
        number_count += 1

print("Number Count:", number_count)
```

Output: `Number Count: 5`

Code above will find for number / float in string, int, or float.

Comment: `isinstance()` does not work the way you think it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
import string
from collections import defaultdict
letters = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits

L = ['8', 'K' , '&' ,'2', '$' , '3' , 'T','R']

results = defaultdict(int)
for x in L:
    if x in letters:
        results["letters"] += 1
    elif x in digits:
        results["digits"] += 1
    else:
        results["special"] += 1

print(dict(results))
# {'digits': 3, 'letters': 3, 'special': 2}
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/3513b9b65b)

Comment: It doesn't,  but if OP needs it (not specified in the question) should be able to implement it easily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/736050/797495

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string` module:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation
>>> L = ['8', 'K' , '&' ,'2', '$' , '3' , 'T','R']
>>> def categorical_counter(lst, category):
...     if category == 'letters':
...             return sum(1 for char in lst if char in ascii_letters)
...     elif category == 'numbers':
...             return sum(1 for char in lst if char in digits)
...     else:
...             return sum(1 for char in lst if char in punctuation)
...
>>> categorical_counter(L, 'numbers')
3
```

Comment: How could float be a character?

Comment: @Ch3steR OP never mentioned `floats` on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isdigit()` and `str.isalpha()` to check if characters/strings are numbers or letters, for example

```
L = ['8', 'K' , '&' ,'2', '$' , '3' , 'T','R']
number_count = 0
letter_count = 0
symbol_count = 0

for i in L:
    if i.isdigit(): # If string is only numeric digits
        number_count += 1
    elif i.isalpha(): # If string is only alphabetical characters
        letter_count += 1
    else: # Assume the rest are symbols
        symbol_count += 1
```

There are many other functions you can use to check what the string contains: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
l=["wael", "dd", ";D"]
l.clear()
print("Input the list size")
n=(int(input()))
for i in range(1,n+1):
 print("fill spot",i,"of the list with")
 l.append(input())
d=0
for data in l:
    if data.isnumeric():
     d=d+1
print("number=",d)
```