# I have a python code and a json file, I can't change the string to float

Tags: python

Python Code:

```
import json

bankstatementjson = open('bankstatement_sept_20.json', 'r')
bankstatement = bankstatementjson.read()

bankstm = json.loads(bankstatement)

for x in bankstm:
    konto_ut = (x["FIELD7"])
    print(float(konto_ut))

for i in bankstm:
    konto_inn = (i["FIELD8"])
    print(float(konto_inn))
```

**Json Data**

```
    {
      "FIELD1": "2020-09-01",
      "FIELD2": "2020-09-02",
      "FIELD3": "50001685147",
      "UTGÅENDE SALDO": "NO1300000000000",
      "9759,52": "Visa",
      "FIELD6": "*9808 31.08 Nok 22.00 Extra Bislett Kurs: 1.0000",
      "FIELD7": "22,00",
      "FIELD8": ""
    },
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: this will help [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Comment: @deadshot why didn't you put this as a duplicate? sounds like one to me...

Comment: Make your program resistant to bad input. Exceptions use try+catch, find examples on internet and learn to use them everywhere where your class communicates with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the one with a comma, it should be changed to a `.` which is the standard for decimal points in Python:

```py
konto_ut = x["FIELD7"].replace(",", ".")
print(float(konto_ut)) # 22.0
```

For empty strings, you can check if it's empty before printing as a float:

```py
konto_inn = i["FIELD8"]
print(float(konto_inn) if (konto_inn != "") else 0) # 0
```

Another option would be to catch the exception which will avoid other potential issues with float conversions:

```py
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

```py
konto_inn = i["FIELD8"]
if (is_number(konto_inn):
    print(float(konto_inn))
else:
    print("Not a number")
```

Comment: it would be better to check `isnumeric()` after replace then convert it

Comment: `"FIELD7": "22,00"` I think it is a typo. OP is getting error for `"FIELD8": ""`