# How can I use the ValueError function correctly?

Tags: python, string, input, valueerror

This is my code:

```
from time import sleep

def Kontostand_Berechnen():
    if float(Kontostand_Nachfragen) >= float(Preis_Nachfragen):
        sleep(1)
        print("")
        print("Du hast genug Geld!")
        print("")
        sleep(1)
    else:
        sleep(1)
        print("")
        print("Du hast nicht genug Geld!")
        print("")
        sleep(1)

sleep(1)
print("")
Kontostand_Nachfragen = input("Wie viel Geld hast du?: ")
sleep(2)
print("")
Preis_Nachfragen = input("Wie viel kostet das Produkt?: ")
if ValueError:
    print("")
    sleep(1)
    print("Bitte nur Zahlen eingeben! Kein Text!")
    print("")
    sleep(1)
else:
    Kontostand_Berechnen()
```

I wrote this code just for practice and for fun. The print text is german. But I don't think that's hindering. I would like that if the user writes text and not a number, an error message is received. But that doesn't work as hoped. With this code, I ALWAYS get the error message, even when I write numbers.
(I'm sure the code is not very understandable. I also only started using Python recently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving the error because `if else` clauses aren't for checking for errors. That why python have [try except clauses](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Following on my answer here [Check if String can be Converted to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345057/is-there-built-in-way-to-check-if-string-can-be-converted-to-float/64345311#64345311), you might want to take a look into to take a look into [try except clause](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and check if the user put a number as input. Then, you will be able to treat `input`'s that aren't numbers, like:

```py
try:
    your_input = float(input("")) # fill in with input text
except Exception as e:
    raise ValueError("") # here you fill in the message you want to give to users
```

However you might be able to check that when you do `float(input("message"))` you are already receiving a `ValueError` with a standard message, so with the code above you can just edit that message (putting it in german, for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of the `ValueError` you need to use [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). You will deal with the error in the `except` block. A simplified example might look like:

```
while True:
    try:
        Preis_Nachfragen = float(input("Wie viel kostet das Produkt?: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Bitte nur Zahlen eingeben! Kein Text!")

print(Preis_Nachfragen)
```