# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'erght'

Tags: python

```
n = input("enter a number:")
if (float(n))> 0:
    print('Positive') 
elif (float(n))< 0:
    print('Negative')
elif n== '0': 
    print('Zero')
else:
    print('not a number')
```

Everything works as intended except for when i input something like 'erght'.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enter a string, then `float(n)` will throw and error. You should use a try-except block.

```py
n = input("enter a number:")
try:
    n = float(n)
    if n>0:
        print('Positive') 
    elif n<0:
        print('Negative')
    else: 
        print('Zero')
except:
    print('not a number')
```

Comment: Although, to avoid accidentally catching irrelevant errors, that should be `except ValueError:`.