# Is there any way to find whether a value in string is a float or not in python?

Tags: python, string, isinstance

I have a problem with string, I am aware that using `isdigit()` we can find whether an integer in the string is an int or not but how to find when its float in the string. I have also used `isinstance()` though it didn't work. Any other alternative for finding a value in the string is float or not??

My code:

```
v = '23.90'
isinstance(v, float)
```

which gives:

```
False
```

Excepted output:

```
True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string represents an int, without using try/except?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just cast it to float or int, and then catch an eventual exception like this:

```
try:
    int(val)
except:
    print("Value is not an integer.")
try:
    float(val)
except:
    print("Value is not a float.")
```

You can return `False` in your `except` part and `True` after the cast in the `try` part, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

```
def in_float_form(inp):
   can_be_int = None
   can_be_float = None
   try:
      float(inp)
   except:
      can_be_float = False
   else:
      can_be_float = True
   try:
      int(inp)
   except:
      can_be_int = False
   else:
      can_be_int = True
   return can_be_float and not can_be_int
```

```
In [4]: in_float_form('23')
Out[4]: False

In [5]: in_float_form('23.4')
Out[5]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the number is integer or not by isdigit(), and depending on that you can return the value.

```
s = '23'

try:
    if s.isdigit():
        x = int(s)
        print("s is a integer")
    else:
        x = float(s)
        print("s is a float")
except:
    print("Not a number or float")
```

Comment: What if  `s = "text"` ?

Comment: @Ruan This try, expect block will handle the edge case of s = "text".

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way would be to convert it to float, then back to string again, and then compare it to the original string - something like this:

```
v = '23.90'
try:
    if v.rstrip('0') == str(float(v)).rstrip('0'):
        print("Float")
    else:
        print("Not Float")
except:
    print("Not Float!")
```