# Python - Check all the key - value pairs in a dict and convert to int or float

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dict like this:

```
[{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': '107844640', 'End': '107844640'}]
```

Almost all the key values are strings, not all of them, but almost (I don't know why).

I would like to check all the key values and convert the `strings` to `int or float` only if the string contains numbers. `'10.020'` should be a `float`, `'10.020abc'` should remain as a `string` and '123' should be an `int`.

This is the desired result:

```
[{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': 107844640, 'End': 107844640}]
```

I did something similar in JavaScript with `Number()`.

Is there any pythonic way to achieve that?

Comment: Not really. You can implement your own `number()` function and use a dictionary comprehension to transform your dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a nice little function to parse the keys/values:

```
def try_convert(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
```

And now use it! For some dictionary `d`,

```
d = {try_convert(k): try_convert(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Note that this works with [anything that can be converted to float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929881/365102). That may or may not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
original_values = [{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': '107844640', 'End': '107844640'}]

dictionary = original_values[0]
for key in dictionary:
    try:
        dictionary[key] = int(dictionary[key])
    except:
        try:
            dictionary[key] = float(dictionary[key])
        except:
            pass
output = [dictionary]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code tries to convert the string to float, then checks if that's a integer and updates the original dictionary accordingly.

```
dict = {'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': '107844640', 'End': '107844640.100'}
print('Before: ', dict)
for key, value in dict.items():
    try:
        v = float(value)
        if v.is_integer():
            v = int(v)
        d = {key: v}
        dict.update(d)
    except ValueError:
        continue

print('After: ', dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': '107844640', 'End': '107844640.100'}
{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': 107844640, 'End': 107844640.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
dictEx = [{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': '107844640', 'End': '107844640.323'}]
for k in dictEx[0]:
    try:dictEx[0][k] = int(dictEx[0][k])
    except Exception as e:
        try:dictEx[0][k] = float(dictEx[0][k])
        except:pass
```

We check if a value can be turned to int or float and change it based on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some similar answers, but this would do the trick using a list comprehension without altering the original input.

```
def convert_value(value):
    try:
        v_float = float(value)
        if v_float.is_integer():
            return int(v_float)
        else:
            return v_float
    except ValueError:
        return value



input_l = [{'Chr': 'chrX', 'Start': '107844640', 'End': '107844640'},
           {'Chr': '126chrX', 'Start': '0.50', 'End': '1'}]
output_l = [{k: convert_value(v) for k,v in doc.items()} for doc in input_l]
```