# How to check if input is string or float in Python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, user-input, python-3.9

I can check integer with **isdigit()** or **isnumeric()**, but they don't work for float.

```
    variable = input("Enter anything: \n")
    #entered a float number: 3.1
    print(variable.isdigit()) #returns false
    
    if variable.isnumeric() and variable.find('.')==-1: #isnumeric also returns false
        variable = int(variable)
    elif variable.isnumeric() and variable.find('.')>=0:
        variable = float(variable)
    
    print("is it a string? : ")
    print(isinstance(variable, str)) #TRUE
    print("is it an integer? : ")
    print(isinstance(variable, int)) #false
    print("Is it a float number? : ")
    print(isinstance(variable, float)) #FALSE
```

Comment: [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Comment: Figured it out. First used **isalpha()** to see if it is string. If not string, used **isnumeric()** to check if it is an integer. if none of these returns true, then it is a float

`a = input("Enter the first number: \n")
 
if a.isalpha():
    print("First input is not a number")
    a = input("Enter a new number: \n")
elif a.isnumeric():
    a = int(a)
else:
    a = float(a)`