# Problem allowing users to enter floating numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code where a user needs to enter float as an input in order to calculate pressure for the cycle. I handled things as strings and non-negative inputs but can't figure out how to enable my users to enter floating numbers (2.5, 1.6 etc) without getting an error or getting stuck in a loop. Here's my code:

```
psrc = input("Enter starting pressure for source: ") # Druck Quelle [Pa] / pressure source 
    while psrc.isnumeric() == False or float(psrc) <=0 or float(psrc) >=3: 
        print ("Starting pressure must be numeric value in range 0-3. Please enter valid pressure value.")
        psrc = input("Enter new pressure: ")
```

EDIT: Figured it out.
Thank you all for ideas. Problem solved by adding a function which checks for the value and returns boolean to the loop and calculations carry on.
Function:

```
def is_float(n):
  try:
    float(n)
    return True
  except:
    return False
```

New loop definition:

```
psrc = input("Enter starting pressure for source: ") # Druck Quelle [Pa] / pressure source 
while is_float(psrc) != True or float(psrc) <=0 or float(psrc) >=3: 
    print ("Starting pressure must be numeric value in range 0-3. Please enter valid pressure value.")
    psrc = input("Enter new pressure: ")
```

Comment: share error you are getting for the given input

Comment: If I type integers, it passes, but any floating number just keeps looping. For example: 2 would complete the calculation but, 2.1 would loop through since isnumeric() returns false. Is there any way to bypass this? Without isnumeric(), I'm getting ValueError, can't cast string to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
x=False
while not x:
    try:
        psrc = float(input("Enter starting pressure for source: ")) # Druck Quelle [Pa] / pressure source 
        x=True
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter valid decimal number.')
print(psrc)
```

Comment: @fatima. Yep, took advantage of the fact that ```float``` raises a value error if it can't convert it to decimals

Answer (score 1):

`str(int(psrc)).isnumeric()` will help you solve issue i guess.

Comment: ```int``` will fail if there are letters or anything else in the string

Answer (score 1):

i can offer you two ways:
1.

```py
def is_it_float(num:str):
    if num.count(".")>1:
        return False
    num = num.split(".")
    for i in num:
        if not i.isnumeric():
            return False
    return True
```

2. 

```py
def is_it_float(num:str):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

`psrc.isnumeric()` checks if the string only contains numbers so it returns `False` because of the decimal separator. You need to define a function that checks if your string is a float and use that instead:

```
while is_string_float(psrc) == False or float(psrc) <=0 or float(psrc) >=3: 
...
```

Is string a float: [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the answer internally, then check for decimals, and if they occur, convert to string.

Comment: That's a nice idea but I'm not sure how to do it properly considering this loop is in a bigger loop and several other inputs depend on this one. I need a fast calculation but still handle various inputs.