# Saving columns from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to write a code that reads a csv file and can save each columns as a specific variable. I am having difficulty because the header is 7 lines long (something I can control but would like to just ignore if I can manipulate it in code), and then my data is full of important decimal places so it can not change to int( or maybe string?) I've also tried just saving each column by it's placement in the file but am struggling to run it. Any ideas?
[Image shows my current code that I have slimmed to show important parts and circles data that prints in my console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTo0q.png)

Comment: Include your code and output as [formatted text](/help/formatting), not a screenshot. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953). You also need to provide an example of the csv file you're reading, and show your code to do the thing you're asking about. Also: what does converting to int have to do with saving columns? Your question is very unclear. Please show your expected output and actual output

Answer (score 0):

> save each columns as a specific variable

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('file.csv')
x_col = df['X']
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is how to iterate through the columns, no matter how many there are. (Which is what I think you are asking.) Then this code should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
data = pd.read_csv('optitest.csv', skiprows=6)

for column in data.columns:
    # You will need to define what this save() method is.
    # Just placing it here as an example.
    save(data[column])
```

The line about formatting your data as a number or a string was a little vague. But if it's decimal data, then you need to use float. See [#9637665](https://stackoverflow.com/a/736050/9637665).

Comment: In the future, please follow the advice from @Pranav Hosangadi for making the question easier to answer :)