# Why does my validation attempt in python accept letters, when I request it to only accept integers and floats?

Tags: python

I was recently working on some programming challenges to increase my proficiency in python until I came to a dead end with one of the challenges. The challenge is to allow the user to input: the hourly wage of a worker; the bonus pay for each item made; the number of hours worked; the number of items made. I decided to add some validation to my program but ran into an error when checking if the bonus pay was a number or decimal. My code for the program is as follows:

```
hourly_pay = input("Please enter the rate of pay for 1 hour: ")

if hourly_pay.isnumeric() == False:
  while hourly_pay.isnumeric() == False:
    print("Invalid input")
    hourly_pay = input("Please enter the rate of pay for 1 hour: ")

bonus_pay = input("Please enter the bonus pay for each car made (in £'s): ")

if bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False and bonus_pay.isdecimal == False:
  while bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False or bonus_pay.isdecimal() == False:
    print("Invalid input")
    bonus_pay = input("Please enter the bonus pay for each car made (in £'s): ")

hours_worked = input("Please enter the number of hours worked: ")

if hours_worked.isnumeric() == False or int(hours_worked) > 15:
  while hours_worked.isnumeric() == False or int(hours_worked) > 15:
    print("Invalid input")
    hours_worked = input("Please enter the number of hours worked: ")

cars_made = input(f"Please enter the number of cars made in {hours_worked} hours: ")

if cars_made.isnumeric() == False:
  while cars_made.isnumeric() == False:
    print("Invalid input")
    cars_made = input(f"Please enter the number of cars made in {hours_worked}: ")

total_pay = (int(hourly_pay) * int(hours_worked)) + (float(bonus_pay) * int(cars_made))

print(f"The pay owed is £{total_pay}")
```

The issue is with the following piece of code:

```
bonus_pay = input("Please enter the bonus pay for each car made (in £'s): ")

if bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False and bonus_pay.isdecimal == False:
  while bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False or bonus_pay.isdecimal() == False:
    print("Invalid input")
    bonus_pay = input("Please enter the bonus pay for each car made (in £'s): ")
```

Every time I enter a letter, the if statement accepts it and does not start the loop.

I was wondering if anyone knew what I did wrong and if they could help me fix it?

Comment: you don't need to check for both `.isnumeric` and `.isdecimal` because `.isnumeric` already checks if it is a decimal and then some more: https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-string-isdecimal-method/

Comment: I used just .isnumeric(), and while it did enter the loop - decimals were not accepted.

Comment: what you mean by decimals? `.isnumeric` checks if the string contains decimals and if it does contain only those then it returns True so it definitely did work, also for example: `if bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False` can be shortened to `if not bonus_pay.isnumeric():`

Comment: I entered the code you put and it still did not work. It just outputs the "Invalid Input" and then enters the while loop. I even tested removing the isnumeric() and using just isdecimal() and the same thing happened. I enter 0.10 every time but it does not accept it (but if i enter - say 4 - the code runs as accepted)

Comment: yes, `.isnumeric` (or `.isdecimal` or `.isdigit`) will return False if the string contains a dot, if you wan to check if the given string can be converted to float then you have to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you are not calling the isdecimal() method in this piece of code:

```py
if bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False and bonus_pay.isdecimal == False:
```

when should it be:

```py
if bonus_pay.isnumeric() == False and bonus_pay.isdecimal() == False:
```

Comment: btw, it is enough to call only `.isnumeric`, it checks for the same things as `.isdecimal` and more additional things

Comment: Thank you for that! However, that still didn't fix my problem