# how to check there are no characters where we need only integer values in python

Tags: python

consider my Dataframe

```
       calories  duration
  0       420        50.55
  1       380        40.48
  2       390        food
```

I need to ensure that the duration doesn't contain character
i tried

```
if df["duration"].isdigit():
    print("True")
else:
    print('The input is not a valid number')
```

but it gives error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Comment: You probably need to do this for each [value in the series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html#pandas.Series.values).

Comment: What does `"50.55".isdigit()` return? For a solution to this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929881/15261315).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.str.isdigit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) on you `Series` object. it gives you a `True` or `False` value for each element in the `Series`. Then you should check that all generated values are `True`. You can do that by calling [`.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) on the resulting series.

If your `duration` column is of type `str`, this will give you the answer.

```py
df['duration'].str.isdigit().all()
```