# Making a more in depth python calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean, calculator

```
first = input("first #:")
operator = input("operator: ")
second = input("second #:")


is_float = true ? false

if (is_float == true) {
 first = float()
 second = float()

} else if (is_float == false) {
  first = int()
  second = int()
}

print(first + operator + second )
```

I am practicing python and i want to make a more indepth calculator that has 2 numbers and various operators for adding subtracting multiplying etc and i want it to switch between a true or false boolean whether or not its a float number.
im not quite sure how to do this would someone be willing to explain how booleans work in python?
I completely understand not spoon feeding but im not sure how to finish this

Comment: `is_float = true ? false` What is this supposed to mean?  Is this meant to be actual code?

Comment: You can check for the presence of a decimal point in the input string.  If there is one, then you can assume the value is a float, otherwise you can assume integer.

Comment: @JohnGordon scientific notation may not have decimal point in it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python) describes correct way the best I guess. Although there is no clear question of what OP is struggling to achieve

Comment: Your first problem is that the code you are writing isn't Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, so you can check for the presence of a decimal point.

If there is one, use `float()` to convert the input string, otherwise use `int()`.

```
if '.' in first:
    first = float(first)

else:
    first = int(first)
```

Comment: There'd also better be first.isnumeric() before if-else I think

Comment: @sudden_appearance A decimal point would make that automatically false, would it not?  Also I think you meant `isdigit()`.

Comment: Oh, you are right, it does result in False.

Answer (score -1):

You could check if the floor value of the number differs from the number itself, giving `is_float = (first - math.floor(first) < 0.00001)`, in this second case you will have to import the `math` package as `import math` at the top of your file.

But you will have to parse a number from the input like this:

```
first  = float(input("first #:"))
second = float(input("second #:"))
```

You cast the inputs to floats, and then chck if the floats are not just 'whole numbers'.

Comment: `is_float = isinstance(first, float)` This can't work, because it presumes the code has _already_ decided to call `int()` or `float()` on the user input string.  But the question is -- how does the code _make_ that decision in the first place?

Comment: soryy you're right