# Python equivalent to C strtod

Tags: python, strtod

I am working on converting parts of a C++ program to Python, but I have some trouble replacing the C function [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/).
The strings I'm working on consists of simple mathmatical-ish equations, such as "KM/1000.0". The problem is that the both constants and numbers are mixed and I'm therefore unable to use float().

How can a Python function be written to simulate `strtod` which returns both the converted number and the position of the next character?

Comment: Can't you just split up the string beforehand?

Comment: Do you need to parse exponential notation, too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/python-and-regex-question-extract-float-double-value/385597#385597

Comment: Here is the c code from Python's source for this, if you want to re-implement -- http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/strtod.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing functions that would do that.

However, it's pretty easy to write one using regular expressions:

```
import re

# returns (float,endpos)
def strtod(s, pos):
  m = re.match(r'[+-]?\d*[.]?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', s[pos:])
  if m.group(0) == '': raise ValueError('bad float: %s' % s[pos:])
  return float(m.group(0)), pos + m.end()

print strtod('(a+2.0)/1e-1', 3)
print strtod('(a+2.0)/1e-1', 8)
```

A better overall approach might be to build a [lexical scanner](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) that would tokenize the expression first, and then work with a sequence of tokens rather than directly with the string (or indeed go the whole hog and build a yacc-style parser).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple C `strtod` wrapper:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double strtod_wrap(const char *nptr, char **endptr)
{
   return strtod(nptr, endptr);
}
```

compile with:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libstrtod.dll strtod.c
```

(if you're using Python 64 bit, the compiler must be 64-bit as well)

and call it using `ctypes` from python (linux: change `.dll` to `.so` in the lib target and in the code below, this was tested on Windows):

```
import ctypes

_strtod = ctypes.CDLL('libstrtod.dll')
_strtod.strtod_wrap.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
_strtod.strtod_wrap.restype = ctypes.c_double

def strtod(s):
    p = ctypes.c_char_p(0)
    s = ctypes.create_string_buffer(s.encode('utf-8'))
    result = _strtod.strtod_wrap(s, ctypes.byref(p))
    return result,ctypes.string_at(p)

print(strtod("12.5hello"))
```

prints:

```
(12.5, b'hello')
```

(It's not as hard as it seems, since I learned how to do that just 10 minutes ago)

Useful Q&As about `ctypes`

- [Calling C functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647186/calling-c-functions-in-python)
- [Issue returning values from C function called from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803121/issue-returning-values-from-c-function-called-from-python)

Comment: Creating the wrapper seems unnecessary; you should be able to do this with `strtod` directly.

Comment: that would be even better. I have to test that first :)

Comment: You should be able to load `strtod` from a platform-specific existing shared library file. `ctypes.cdll.msvcrt` should work on Windows. I believe it's commonly `cdtypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')` on Linux, but I don't know how universal that is. It's probably also possible to compile your own file to access `strtod` from, though I'm not sure what the details of that would look like. (`#include <stdlib.h>` on its own seems like it might work.)

Comment: I have tried that single stdlib.h include alone in the C file and it seems that the `strtod` symbol isn't linked so it doesn't work (python cannot find it). Sticking to the empty wrapper for now. It's working, and it's portable at source level apart from the .dll/.so part. As stated in the answer, I'm not a ctypes specialist. Just made it work (and was impressed by the simplicity of the python code).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression for this:

```
import re
mystring = "1.3 times 456.789 equals 593.8257 (or 5.93E2)"
def findfloats(s):
    regex = re.compile(r"[+-]?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[+-]?\d+)?\b", re.I)
    for match in regex.finditer(mystring):
        yield (match.group(), match.start(), match.end())
```

This finds all floating point numbers in the string and returns them together with their positions.

```
>>> for item in findfloats(mystring):
...     print(item)
...
('1.3', 0, 3)
('456.789', 10, 17)
('593.8257', 25, 33)
('5.93E2', 38, 44)
```

Comment: I can think of a bunch of valid floats that wouldn't get picked up.

Comment: The regex assumes an integer part. Everything else is optional. If there is a decimal point, a fractional part is required. So `.1` and `1.` won't be picked up. Of course it's trivial to modify the regex if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

parse the number yourself.

a recursive-descent parser is very easy for this kind of input.
first write a grammar:

```
float ::= ipart ('.' fpart)* ('e' exp)*
ipart ::= digit+
fpart ::= digit+
exp   ::= ('+'|'-') digit+
digit = ['0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9']
```

now converting this grammar to a function should be straightforward...

Comment: There should be a `('+'|'-')` before `ipart` in the definition of `float`

Comment: @madphysicist it depends on the context. When parsing single standalone numbers, indeed you need to parse the leading sign. when parsing a numerical expression, you avoid including the sign because it would allow strange expression like "42-+37.2" (I seem to remember that I copied this grammar from the grammar of a well known language)

Comment: `42-+37.2` seems like a reasonable expression to me.

Comment: although it is reasonable to any math-inclined human being, such grammar implies that you can also write `42--37.2`, which confuses a C or C++ parser (but strangely C++ accepts `42-+37.2`). As such, many (most) programming languages treats a leading sign as an unary operator, that is, an entity clearly separated from the following number. and some languages do not allow a unary operator anywhere else than the start of an expression. Anyway, for simple parsing of standalone numbers, the grammar above is indeed missing those unary operators.