# Trying to open a dll written in c with python ctypes and run the function in it, but it comes as int, not a string

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

These are my example source code:

C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
char* sys_open(char* file_name)
{
    char *file_path_var = (char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    FILE *wrt = fopen(file_name, "r");
    fscanf(wrt, "%s", file_path_var);
    fclose(wrt);

    return file_path_var;
}
```

Test.txt

```
test
```

Python

```py
from ctypes import *

libcdll = CDLL("c.dll")
taken_var = libcdll.sys_open("test.txt")
print("VAR: ", taken_var)
```

Result

```sh
VAR: 4561325
```

So I'm just getting a random number. What should i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue returning values from C function called from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803121/issue-returning-values-from-c-function-called-from-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the true one.

The python file was wrong, must be:

```py
from ctypes import *

libcdll = CDLL("c.dll")
taken_var = libcdll.sys_open("test.txt")
print("VAR: ", c_char_p(taken_var).value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C developer, but isn't `sys_open` returning a pointer?. Last time I checked pointers are WORD sized memory addresses in HEX, so it might make sense that python sees a numerical value in HEX and converts it to a decimal?. Maybe what you want to return from your C funcion is `&file_path_var`

Comment: nope i taking an error about it. warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Comment: Then the problem is clearer. Your C function is returning the memory address of a variable that's out fo scope already. 

This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897914/c-warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable
And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380758/error-function-returns-address-of-local-variable

Might clarify things