# Regex to detect "Invalid float"

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to detect invalid floating point numbers in the sense that they cannot have two decimal points. Here is what I have, but it's not working:

```
REAL = re.compile("^\d+\.\d+$")
```

*Edit:* I'm using python. In the big picture I'm writing a lexer to recognize a miniature version of the C syntax. A 2.3.4 is recognized as invalid, but a 13.4.5 is not. It has something to do with that, I suppose.

---

Sorry for the poorly formatted question. After reading through some comments I found the error elsewhere in the code. Turns out that using `re.compile("0") and re.compile("1")` earlier in my code was causing any sequence starting with a 1/0 to be 'picked up' as valid, despite whatever the remainder of the sequence. Simply adding `"0$" and "1$"` fixed my problem.

Comment: WHAT'S THE LANGUAGE ? Please read the description of the tag you use.

Comment: @dystroy this looks like python

Comment: That looks correct. On what strings is it working/not working?

Comment: @Clever, some more context, please. *What* exactly is not working? Some input and expected output would help. How are you running your test(s)?

Comment: That is, it matches valid floats. Are you trying to match invalid floats?

Comment: "They cannot have two decimal places" Are you trying to match floats that have this property, floats that don't have this property, or everything that isn't a float with two decimal places?

Comment: I'm trying to find any invalid floats and point them out as a syntax error. I meant two decimal points, not two decimal places*, oops.

Comment: When I run it, it rejects both `1.3.4` and `13.4.5`.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If I take your code, and then do `REAL.match('13.4.5')`, it returns `None`, exactly as it does for `1.3.4`. My guess is that there's a problem somewhere _else_ in your lexer that's causing, e.g., the `13.4` to get passed to this regex, and `.5` as another token. But without knowing anything else about your code, there's no way to guess what causes that.

Comment: Can you show us a full, working bit of code that demonstrate what's going wrong?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for pointing this out. I was earlier detecting for true/false as '0' or '1' but failed to include a $ to terminate the sequence, meaning any float starting with a 0 or 1 and continuing with two decimal points would get 'picked up' earlier.

Comment: @Clever: That's exactly why you need to give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead of giving a random bit of code that may or may not be whether the problem lies, and can't be tested or debugged.

Comment: As a side note, trying to build a lexer out of regexps for a language with the ambiguous lexical structure like C is probably not the best approach.

Comment: related: [Python and regex question, extract float/double value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/python-and-regex-question-extract-float-double-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not actually in this code at all.

As a quick test shows, with `REAL = re.compile("^\d+\.\d+$")`, `re.match('13.4.5')` returns `None`, just as `re.match('2.3.4')`.

The problem must be that some earlier code is matching `'13.4.5'` in some way that causes it to either eat the rest of the token, or eat enough of it that what remains (e.g., `'4.5'`) is a valid float. Without seeing your code, nobody can guess what exactly the problem is.

But, as it turns out, you've got another regex that matches `'1'` without a terminator, so whatever code you have to builds lexemes out of regex matches accepts all of `'13.4.5'`. Again, without seeing your code, nobody can guess why exactly that happens…

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be doing this:

```
floatStr = '12.3.4'
try:
    float(floatStr)
except ValueError:
    # do something
    pass
```

In other words: try to parse the string, and if it fails, it's because the format is not that of a floating point number. No need to mess around with regular expressions here (the format of a valid floating-point number can be a bit tricky to get right) - just let the standard conversion function do the heavy lifting for you!

Comment: That doesn't solve his problem. It passes floats with two decimal places, like `12.34`, which is what he specifically said he wants to stop.

Comment: @abarnert I think he meant two "decimal places" as in two `.`s.

Comment: @abarnert see the other comment, A.R.S. is right.

Comment: @A.R.S.: Yes, it looks like he's changed his question, first to give an example `13.4.5`, and then to change "decimal place" to "decimal point". So, this is answering what he _meant_ to ask, which is even better than answering what he actually asked. :)

Comment: I still wouldn't use the variable name `str`.. and add a `pass` within the `except` scope. am i too obsessive?

Comment: @kirpit no, they're fine suggestions. I updated my answer with them.