# Find numbers in string, modify and re-join

Tags: python, regex

*Probem*:

I have a **string containing different numbers, math signs and words**, e.g.

```
str = ".1**2 + x/(10.0 - 2.E-4)*n_elts"
```

I would like to **extract all numbers and keep the parts between the numbers** so I can place it together again later (after working on the numbers).

```
lst = [".1", "**", "2", " + ", "x/(", "10.0", " - ", "2.E-4", ")*n_elts"]
```

would be one of many acceptable results. The elements which are not numbers can be split up further in any arbitrary way, since the next step will be

```
"".join(process(l) for l in lst)
```

where process could look like this
(suggestions for a better way to check `l` is a number welcome):

```
def process(l):
    try:
        n = float(l)
    except ValueError:
        return l
    else:
        return work_on_it(l)
```

*Current state:*

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136580/1243951) I figured out how to keep the deliminators and worked my way to

```
lst = re.split('( |\+|\-|\*|/)', ".1**2 + x/(10.0 - 2.E-4)*n_elts")
```

Now I need to somehow avoid splitting the `2.E-4`.

I tried to work out a regex (vi syntax, hope this is universal)
that covers all numbers that could possibly appear and think

```
\d*\.\d*[E|e]*[|+|-]*\d*
```

should be ok.

One strategy would be to somehow get this into `re`.

I also found a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703508/1243951) that seems to do the number matching part.
It might be a bit more complex than I need, but mainly I do not know how to combine it with the keeping deliminators bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general note: inside character classes you don't use `|`, because it's just treated as another character to be matched. Inside character classes, the allowed characters are simply listed after one another.

To actually solve your problem: since you are keeping the delimiters anyway, it doesn't matter whether you are matching the numbers or the non-numbers right? So simply use

```
lst = re.split(r'(\d*\.\d*[Ee]*[+-]*\d*)', ".1**2 + x/(10.0 - 2.E-4)*n_elts")
```

You might want to improve on that number regex a bit though:

```
lst = re.split(r'((?:\d+\.\d*|\.?\d+)(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?)', ".1**2 + x/(10.0 - 2.E-4)*n_elts")
```

This way, you make the decimal point optional, but require at least one digit before or after it. This also makes the exponential part completely optional, but ensures it's well-formatted if it is present. The `?:` suppresses capturing. Otherwise those inner groups would do the same as the outer set of parentheses, and add the parts that are matched inside to the result of `split` - you don't want that though, because that would give you the complete number, the part before the exponential, and the exponential separately. So you need to use `?:` to suppress the capturing (which is in general a good habit unless you explicitly need capturing).

Finally, note the use of raw strings (the `r` preceding the string literal). Without this escaping can get really ugly (in that you may have to double escape certain regex meta-characters). In Python, you should always use raw strings to denote regex patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit that `re.split()` with a capturing regex returns matches at odd indexes, [example](http://ideone.com/16ytPI):

```
import re

s = ".1**2 + x/(10.0 - 2.E-4)*n_elts"
parts = re.split(r"([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)", s)
parts[1::2] = [str(100 * float(f)) for f in parts[1::2]]
print("".join(parts))
# -> 10.0**200.0 + x/(1000.0 - 0.02)*n_elts
```

where the regex is from [Python and regex question, extract float/double value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/4279).

Comment: @ChrisF: no assumptions. From the docs: *separator components are always found at the same relative indices within the result list*. [Try it](http://ideone.com/16ytPI).

Comment: The odd even trick is nice. It seems unary operators become part of the first number anyways but even `'A'+s` works (which is important for me)