# Python 3 Finding the last number in a string

Tags: python, string, parsing, search, python-3.x

How can I find the last number in any big string?

For eg in the following string I want 47 as the output:

`'tr bgcolor="aa77bb"td>font face="verdana"color="white" size="2">b>Total/b>/font>/td>\td>font face="verdana"color="white" size="2">b>47/b>/font>/td>/tr>'`

PS: We don't know the number. The number 47 is just an example. It can be any number from 0 to 900.

Comment: Is the HTML broken in the source?

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'tr bgcolor="aa77bb"td>font face="verdana"color="white" size="2">b>Total/b>/font>/td>\td>font face="verdana"color="white" size="2">b>47/b>/font>/td>/tr>'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', text)[-1]
'47'
```

If you need to match floating points there's always [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/1219006)

For very long strings this is more efficient:

```
re.search(r'\d+', text[::-1]).group()[::-1]
```

Comment: It gives the inverted answer, I guess. You can just reverse the final string, then.

Comment: Just realised you can just use `re.findall` anyway (was thinking backwards)

Comment: By the way, reversing is way-way better for long strings. But this won't work with referenced regexp for floats, of course.

Comment: @kirelagin I thought that at first, but then I assumed it would never be very useful but I'll add it back

Answer (score 2):

I guess I don't know enough about the implementation details / performance of finding a bunch of results and choosing the last, vs just finding the last to begin with (didn't do any performance comparisons); but, this very well might be faster:

```
>>> text = 'tr bgcolor="aa77bb"td>font face="verdana"color="white" size="2">b>Total/b>/font>/td>\td>font face="verdana"color="white" size="2">b>47/b>/font>/td>/tr>'
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(\d+)\D+$', text).group(1)
'47'
```

Comment: +1 I like this better than `re.findall`. I have a similar second version that I re-added to my answer which short circuits so it would be more efficient (not sure about speed) but this looks nicer

Comment: Replace the '+'s with '*'s to also match the empty string and digits flush right, respectively.  E.g., `re.search(r'(\d*)\D*$', '').group(1)` returns `''`.