# How to parse sub string and get the digit after the substring in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to fetch the digit of the last occurance of the substring

```
input : "abc1  foo barabc2 abc3 abc4 foobar"
output : 4
```

Comment: What about `^.*(\d)`?

Comment: And what have you tried and where are you stuck at?

Comment: use `split` to split it into substrings, iterate through backwords, checking `substring[-1]` to see if it `isdigit()`. If so, punch out, you're done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 Finding the last number in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007257/python-3-finding-the-last-number-in-a-string)

Comment: found a way 
**s.split("abc")[-1][0]**

Comment: @RohanNagalkar this will only work if all your digits are preceded by the string "abc" which is not what you ask in your question

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "abc1  foo barabc2 abc3 abc4 foobar"
print(re.findall('\d+', s)[-1])
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if that's the only thing you want to get then I wouldn't use `regexp` at all, instead:

```
s = "abc1 foo barabc2 abc3 abc4 foobar"
print([c for c in s if c.isdigit()][-1])
```

I hope you were looking for something like that.

Comment: Wow, that will create a whole list with all the digits and at the end only display the last one. It will work but it will be extremely inefficient (imagine a list of one million elements, all of them digits). If you want to use loops, just reverse iterate until the first digit is found and stop there.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki inefficient compared to what, in what context? Compared it to regular expressions? What if I say, that it's meant to be functional programming instead of imperative style?

Comment: If your list has thousand million elements and the last element is a digit, reverse looping will only take one operation. You code will first create a new list of up to thousand million elements (in the case all elements are actually digits) and then just displaying the last one. Inefficient compared to this!

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Obviously. But then why not commented on the regexp solutions? And still, efficiency was not a requirement at all here.