# What is a reliable isnumeric() function for python 3?

Tags: python, regex, validation, python-3.x, isnumeric

I am attempting to do what should be very simple and check to see if a value in an `Entry` field is a valid and real number. The `str.isnumeric()` method does not account for "-" negative numbers, or "." decimal numbers.

I tried writing a function for this:

```
def IsNumeric(self, event):
    w = event.widget
    if (not w.get().isnumeric()):
        if ("-" not in w.get()):
            if ("." not in w.get()):
                w.delete(0, END)
                w.insert(0, '')
```

This works just fine until you go back and type letters in there. Then it fails.

I researched the possibility of using the `.split()` method, but I could not figure out a reliable regex to deal for it.

This is a perfectly normal thing that needs to be done. Any ideas?

Comment: related: [Extract float/double value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/385558/4279)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
try:
    float(w.get())
except ValueError:
    # wasn't numeric
```

Comment: If i had a brain I would have thought of that. There is no reason that cant be wrapped in an IsNumeric function. :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might just need to know whether passing some string to `float` will give a result (i.e. it is a nice numeric value), or an error (i.e. the string doesn't represent a number).  Try this:

```
def isnum(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except:
        return(False)
    else:
        return(True)
```

Comment: Catching everything with a bare `except` is a bad idea.  You also do not need parenthesis around `False` and `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I've just faced this problem.
You can do something like:

```py
if re.sub("[^0-9\\-\\.]", "", "-0.18"):
```