# python regular expression matching either one

Tags: python, regex

I want to create `validNumber` regular expression, but how can I handle a number ".digit" (ex, '.2') case?

```
import re
m = '[-|+]?[[\.\d+]|[\d+\.?\d*]]'

re.findall(m, '.2')
```

Returns `['.', '2']`， expected `['.2']`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/190597

Comment: You may be confusing `[]` with `()` -- they mean completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think `'[-|+]?(\.\d+|\d+\.?\d*)'` will miss negative numbers; assuming the op wanted the - and + as part of the match, `'[+|-]*\d*\.?\d+'` might work better:

```
>>> m = '[+|-]*\d*\.?\d+'
>>> re.findall(m,'.2 fun stuff-13t 34.5s 234.')
['.2', '-13', '34.5', '234']
```