# Python regex extracting floatin values

Tags: python, regex, floating-point, decimal

I have data that has strings with floating numbers like

```
"['0.0'" and '82.00.0' and '82.0\n'
```

and I only want to extract floating points till two/one decimal points like so-

```
"['0.0'" and '82.00.0' and '82.0\n' to 0.0, 82.0, 82.0
```

The data structure is a big quoted CSV like:

`"0.0, 82.00.0,...., 82.0\n"`

I'm iterating through these to store them to the temp

`tempprices.split(',')
 temp =[]
 for n in range(l, len(tempprices)-1):
   temp.append(map(ast.literal_eval,re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+\.\d{1,2}(?!\.*\d)',tempprices[n])))`

where l is some index value.

I want to append these to `temp` like so `[0.0, 82.0, 82.0]`

How to achieve that?

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: I think [`re.findall(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", s)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/3832970) will do. Just adjust the quantifiers.

Comment: Tried this, did not work- `float(re.sub(r'[^0-9.[0-9][0-9]?]', '', price[n]))`

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+\.\d{1,2}(?!\.*\d)", s)`. Or `import ast`, and then `map(ast.literal_eval,re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+\.\d{1,2}(?!\.*\d)',s)) `

Comment: When I use `float(re.findall(r"(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+\.\d{1,2}(?!\.*\d)", s))` I get this 'float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list''

Comment: You can't cast a list to a float type. Try using `ast` as I indicated in the comment above.

Comment: It's giving me `<map object at 0x041EF4F0>`

Comment: Ok, what do you expect to obtain? Please add that to the question together with your attempt posted as a comment. Also, here is a sample Python demo: https://ideone.com/lKfz10.

Comment: Updated the question, I hope you understand what I want to achieve. Thank you for your time though :)

Comment: No, that won't work like this: post the relevant code for us in your question body to be able to help you properly. Also, regarding *I split the line with ","s*: why not use a CSV parser?

Comment: I hope my answer will help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You did not assign the split chunks to a variable (see `tempprices.split(',')`)
- You actually have to extract 1 value, so the `re.sub` can work, but a `re.search` is safer

You may use the following fix:

```
import re

tempprices = "0.0, 82.00.0,...., 82.0\n"
cells = tempprices.split(',')
temp =[]
for t in cells:
    mObj = re.search(r'-?\d+\.\d{1,2}', t)
    if mObj:
        temp.append(float(mObj.group()))
print(temp)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/a3FO9E)

If you can have multiple float values inside each cell, you will have to use `ast.literal_eval` with `re.findall`:

```
for t in cells:
    temp.extend(map(ast.literal_eval, re.findall(r'-?\d+\.\d{1,2}', t)))
         ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ehNlDg)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This finally worked, and I had split the values, just stored them in the same variable. But thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

s = '82.00\n    1.3000   9.1'
result = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d{1,2}', s)
print result
```

**Output:** ['82.00', '1.30', '9.1']

Comment: Yes, and `r'\d+.\d{1,2}'` will also grab `1-11` and `1:11`