# How to find a float in a string - Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I want to find the first float that appears in a string using Python 3.

I looked at other similar questions but I couldn't understand them and when I tried to implement them they didn't work for my case.

An example string would be

`I would like 1.5 cookies please`

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure there's more elegant solution, but this one works for your specific case:

```
s = 'I would like 1.5 cookies please'

for i in s.split():
    try:
        #trying to convert i to float
        result = float(i)
        #break the loop if i is the first string that's successfully converted
        break
    except:
        continue

print(result) #1.5
```

Comment: Really good answer!! Not requiring `regex` and also recognises negative and non-decimal formatted numbers (+1)

Comment: This answers the question perfectly, but might be a bit too broad for the user's definition of "float". Try it with `s = "Infinity is better with 3 cookies."` for example :)

Comment: @pistache yes, perfect observation, same for [`nan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float). I found very good answers for the user's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/extract-float-double-value), they address lots of issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can find this using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), notice this pattern will only return the substring if it's already in `float` type, i.e. decimal fomatting, so something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> matches = re.findall("[+-]?\d+\.\d+", "I would like 1.5 cookies please")
```

As you say you want only the first one:

```
>>> matches[0]
'1.5'
```

Edit: Added `[+-]?` to the pattern for it to recognize negative floats, as pistache recommended!

Comment: The only thing I'd add is `[+-]?` to also capture the sign.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect whitespace separated decimal floats, using `str` methods and removing `-+.`:

```
s = 'I would like 1.5 cookies please'
results = [t for t in s.split() 
           if t.lstrip('+-').replace('.', '', 1).isdigit()]
print(results[0])  #1.5
```

`lstrip` is used to remove the sign only on the lefthand side of the text, and the third argument to `replace` is used to replace only one dot in the text. The exact implementation depends on the how you expect floats to be formatted (support whitespace between sign, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex. below also checks for negative values.

```
import re

stringToSearch = 'I would like 1.5 cookies please'
searchPattern = re.compile(".*(-?[0-9]\.[0-9]).*")
searchMatch = searchPattern.search(stringToSearch)

if searchMatch:
    floatValue = searchMatch.group(1)
else:
    raise Exception('float not found')
```

You can use [PyRegex](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6Ii4qKC0%2FWzAtOV1cXC5bMC05XSkuKiIsImZsYWdzIjowLCJtYXRjaF90eXBlIjoibWF0Y2giLCJ0ZXN0X3N0cmluZyI6Ikkgd291bGQgbGlrZSAxLjUgY29va2llcyBwbGVhc2UifQ%3D%3D) to check the regex.

Comment: This is very inefficient, why would you include the rest of the string in the search pattern, to then fetch a capture group ? `re.search("\d+\.\d+", s)` works fine, does not copy the whole input string, and is much faster (especially as the input string size grows).