# Simple Floating Point regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, floating-point

I'm using [+-]?[0-9]*.[0-9]{1,} this simple regex for detecting simple floating numbers. It's working fine but it's detecting 4.0O0 as a floating point number. Can anyone explain me why ?
i'm doing it using python , the code is given below:

```
    pattern=r'[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]{1,}'
    input_float=input().strip()
    if re.match(pattern,input_float):
         print("True")
    else:
         print("False")
```

Comment: Try matching the beginning and end of the string as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract float/double value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/extract-float-double-value)

Comment: There is an upper-case 'o' (O) in your `4.0O0` - a typo in your question, or your data-source?

Comment: That's actually not a typo that was a test case that was supposed to get failed

Comment: Also i think it is better to modify the pattern as 
" r'[+|-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+' " , because with your pattern it will pass a test case like +-4.50
Which doesn't makes much sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` only matches the given regex at the beginning of the string, but not the end of the string. Use `re.fullmatch` instead to match the entire string with the given regex.

```
if re.fullmatch(pattern,input_float):
```