# Remove all non-numeric part but keep the coma in python

Tags: python

lets say I have a a string such as :

```
line = "tree length for XI:      31.0215"
```

I would liek to only keep the `31.0215` part. 
I tried:

```
print (re.sub("^[0-9]", "",line))
```

but it does not work, the "." is removed, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/extract-float-double-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out.

```
line = "tree length for XI:      31.0215"
for item in line.split():
    try:
        float(item)
        print(float(item))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
result = ''.join([i for i in line if (i.isdigit() or (i == "."))])
```