# Sum of ints in a regex list

Tags: python, regex, list, casting

With a list of ints created from re.findall(), how can we create a sum for the ints?

Example file:

```
A number: 606
Another number could be 52 or 38
Another number below:
55
```

Prints a list created with RegEx captures:

```
import re
fileHandle = open("sample.txt", "r")
for line in fileHandle:
    #RegEx: Match all ints anywhere in line
    num = re.findall("\d+", line)
    print(num)
```

Output:

```
['606']
['52', '38']
[]
['55']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code with explanations in comments

```
import re
sumInts = 0
fileHandle = open("sample.txt", "r")
for line in fileHandle:
    #RegEx: Match all ints anywhere in line
    num = re.findall("\d+", line)
    #Cast list entries to ints (might not be needed?)
    num = [int(i) for i in num]
    #Sums all ints from RegEx capture
    for i in num:
        sumInts = sumInts + i
print(sumInts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the items of the (nested) list from `str` to `int`. You can do so in a single nested generator expression using the `sum` builtin function:

```
>>> sum(int(x) for line in filehandle for x in re.findall(r"\d+", line))    
751
```

Or without nesting, using `read()` to get the entire content of the file (if it's not too big):

```
>>> sum(int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+", filehandle.read()))             
751
```

Or using `map` instead of a generator expression:

```
>>> sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", filehandle.read())))                   
751
```

Or if you want the sums per line (`map` version left as an exercise to the reader):

```
>>> [sum(int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+", line)) for line in filehandle] 
[606, 90, 0, 55]
```

(When you try those in the interactive shell, remember that the file will be "exhausted" after each of those, so you will have to re-open the file before testing the next one. Also note that using `\d+` you might get surprising results if your file contains e.g. floating point numbers or IP addresses.)

Comment: I wonder which one would be faster

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Given that the input is read from a file, I doubt that it matters much. Without the file-reading part (using a multiline string or a list of strings respectively), the double-for-generator is a bit slower than the other two.

Comment: Good point on irregularities with floats and IPs. A capture that matches a pattern containing a maximum of one decimal might do for that, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Reubens4Dinner It might be a bit more complicated, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/1639625).

Comment: @Reubens4Dinner Oh, and of course, if you capture floating point numbers, remember to convert to `float` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred regex solution is to use an iterator and compute the sum as we parse the input string:

```
input = """A number: 606
           Another number could be 52 or 38
           Another number below:
           55"""

sum = 0

for match in re.finditer("\d+", input):
    sum = sum + int(match.group())

print("sum is: " + str(sum))
```

This prints:

```
sum is: 751
```