# Series with mixed elements such as NaNs and alpharithmetic values, from which the numbers need to be kept and converted to float

Tags: string, pandas, numeric, strip

I have a dataframe column which appears as follows and has the following characteristics:

```
>>> df.dtypes
location     object
sensor_1     object
sensor_2    float64

>>> df['sensor_1'].head(4)
0    3 m3/h
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
Name: sensor_1, dtype: object

>>> type(df['sensor_1'][0])
str

>>> type(df['sensor_1'][1])
float
```

My goal is to keep the numeric part and recognise it as `float` from "sensor_1", taking into consideration the fact that there `Nulls` which are recognised already as numeric, as I understand.

I tried a few things which did not work:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['sensor_1'], errors='coerce')  #it did not change anything
```

```
df['sensor_1'].apply(lambda x: x.str[:-5].astype(float) if pd.notnull(x) else x)  
 #tried to strip the last 5 characters if not null and then convert the remaining part to float

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

```
df['sensor_1'].to_string()  #unsure how to go on from there
```

So... running out of ideas really and asking for your help. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), but first convert values to `string`s and last to `floats`:

```
df['sensor_1'] = (df['sensor_1'].astype(str)
                                .str.extract('((\d+\.*\d*))', expand=False)
                                .astype(float))
```

Comment: I am using the first solution which is close the one I had in mind. However, I realised that if all the elements of the column "sensor_1" are NaN, I get ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!```

Comment: @Newbielp - then problem is there are numeric values, so use `df['sensor_1'] = df['sensor_1'].astype(str).str[:-5].astype(float)`

Comment: then I get ```ValueError: could not convert string to float:``` Not sure how to deal with it.I am gonna try the other solutions you have offered for the different cases that exist in my datasets. What does ```extract('(\d+)'``` do?

Comment: @Newbielp - It extract first integer value

Comment: But I may also have numbers that carry decimals, so I would need 5.4 for example...

Comment: @Newbielp - then change `(\d+)`  to `(\d+\.*\d*)` - solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28832504)

Comment: It worked for decimals, but I still have the problem that if "sensor_1" is completely empty, then I am getting the same ```AttributeError```. Maybe I need to do something like ```try: catch``` or optimize the ```if pd.notnull(x) else x```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203089/discussion-between-jezrael-and-newbielp).